# Debugging Vue in Laravel using Visual Studio Code

Tags: laravel, vue.js, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug Vue in a Laravel project using VS Code.

Laravel 8.0, Vue 2.6.12

I already followed [the guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html) at Vue.js website, However, I am getting the error message below in Chrome Console and not able to trigger the breakpoint.

> DevTools failed to load source map ...

Could you please help me with the configuration of VS Code debugger?

Please note that I am using Laravel Mix as well.

```
{
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Vuejs: Chrome",
            "url": "https://studio.local",
            "breakOnLoad": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///*": "${workspaceFolder}/*"
                "webpack:///node_modules/*": "${workspaceFolder}/src/node_modules/*"
            }
        }
```

I also added mix.sourceMaps() into my webpack.mix.js

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

The issue with js files is solved. I have a new issue with debugging .vue files. I don't know what rule I need to add in sourceMapPathOverrides section.

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Vuejs: Chrome",
        "url": "https://site.local",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
        "breakOnLoad": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:///resources/assets/dashboard/js/components/app/layouts/AppDashboardLayout.vue*": "${webRoot}/resources/assets/dashboard/js/components/app/layouts/AppDashboardLayout.vue",

            "webpack:///resources/assets/*": "${webRoot}/resources/assets/*", // NOT WORKING
            "webpack:///./resources/assets/*": "${webRoot}/resources/assets/*", // WORKS FOR JS FILES
            "webpack:///./node_modules/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",
        }
    }
]
```

I have a lot of .vue files under different directories. I cannot add a line for each .vue file.

Do you have any idea what I need to do?
Thank you

Comment: Did you do `mix.sourceMaps()` in your `webpack.mix.js` file ?

Comment: Yes, I added mix.sourceMaps(false, 'source-map'); in my webpack.mix.js

Comment: What are those 2 parameters ? I have never used `sourceMaps` with arguments.

Comment: You're right! It doesn't need any arguments.

Comment: Did it work or is it sill not working ?

Comment: Finally, it worked! Thank you! but I am only able to debug .js files and not .vue files. Do you have any idea what I need to do?

Comment: I do not, if you are able to debug JS, you should also be able to debug .vue, but I am not sure about that, as I debug them always in the chrome dev tools source tab

Comment: OK, I'll try to figure it out! Thank you so much, Matiaslauriti

Comment: I think I found out why the debugger on vue files didn't work. Because I have a query string after the name of files like ContractTable.vue?e2d1 . I could add a rule under sourceMapPathOverrides like ../*.vue* and then it worked but as I have a lot of directories & files in my assets, I cannot write a rule for each one. Do you have any idea how I can use a right rule? Thank you

Comment: Oh, yes, when it compiles it does stuff like that, I have no idea how that works, but I do see that too when I use Source tab, the files have that ending too. I am not skilled enough with JS and all its environment to help you with that.

Comment: You helped me a lot! Thank you very much